# Magento / Authorize.net - "Credit card type is not allowed for this payment method"

Tags: magento, credit-card, authorize.net

I have a client that's running a Magento Community Edition site - version 1.3.2.4  - they've been using PayPal for payments for over a year with no issues at all.

Last week we added Authorize.net as an option and configured it to authorize and capture payments. They have their Authorize.net account set to then connect up with their Sage Pay account on the accounting side.

Everything works great until attempting to submit a payment - no matter what card type is selected using the Authorize.net choices (Visa / MC / Dis / AMEX) upon submitting the form, it throws a Magento alert of "Credit card type is not allowed for this payment method".

I've been on Google and the Magento forums for a couple hours now trying to track down the issue, but I've come up empty. Most suggestions I found were to clear the cache - I've done so, both in the admin as well as clearing out var/cache and var/sessions, but it's made no difference.

We've contacted Authorize.net and verified that the account is active and ready to receive transactions from those 4 card types.

Any thoughts on why this would be occurring and how to correct it?

Thanks for your help,
Jonathon

Comment: Not really related, but there have been drastic improvements in both the PayPal module and the Authorize.net module since 1.3.x. You may want to suggest an upgrade.

Comment: We may have to go that route.

Comment: Am also having this issue but only in GraphQL API 'placeOrder' query. But it is working fine in the Magento front-end. My Magento version is 2.4.3 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @VigneshBala : Were you able to placeorder using graphql API now ?

Comment: @nikin Not yet fixed, still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This typically means the the account was set up as card present instead of card not present. Having the account changed to the right type will solve this issue.

Comment: Did some Googling - thank you for your suggestion, I'll follow up with them to verify. http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/What-is-the-difference-between-Card-Not-Present-CNP-and-Card/ba-p/16916

Comment: We verified with Authorize.net that all of the settings are right on their end for receiving payments, and that the account is indeed set up as Card Not Present. I've generated a fresh Transaction Key just to make sure, but we continue to get the alert error prompt, and Authorize isn't seeing anything coming through on their end. I'm not seeing an Authorize.net error code in the logs either. Any other thoughts on where this might be coming from? Thanks again, Jonathon

Comment: were you able to solve this? i know how difficult it is to remember such old things, but if you remember, can u let us know what you did?